# Background image rotator preloader

Tags: javascript, image-preloader

I am building a site that includes three full screen images that rotate on the home page. I've used the JavaScript & CSS shown below to code this functionality. The images are displaying OK, but I'm getting a white screen between images. I suspect these images need to be preloaded but I don't know how to write the JavaScript for that. I'd also like to fade the images in & out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The site is http://highlandscashiers.com

Comment: What have you tried so far ? could you please post the code ! You have used any plugin?

Comment: I tried to post the code in my question & it wouldn't let me. Said the code wasn't indented properly. I tried to change this but it didn't work. You can see the code on the website under view source. No plugins used.